# Looking up one table, comparing to a second "reference" table, and outputting multiple lines for a single entry from first table

Tags: excel

I'm looking to take one table (Name to Dept) and look up corresponding entries on a second (Dept to Plan) to get a third column that's "flat", showing all plans each name corresponds to.

I have:

| Name | Dept |
| --- | --- |
| a | x |
| b | y |
| c | z |
| d | z |

and

| Dept | plan |
| --- | --- |
| x | 1 |
| x | 2 |
| y | 2 |
| z | 1 |
| z | 3 |

I want:

| Name | Plan |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 1 |
| c | 3 |
| d | 1 |
| d | 3 |

I keep getting hung up on trying to get multiple entries for multiple names within a single dept.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an SQL statement against the two ranges:

```sql
SELECT Name, Plan
FROM [Sheet1$] AS t1
INNER JOIN [Sheet2$] AS t2 ON t1.Dept = t2.Dept
```

Use the SQL statement to open a recordset, as follows:

```vb
Const filepath As String = "C:\path\to\excel\file.xlsx"

Dim connectionString As String
connectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=""" & filepath & """;" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"""

Dim sql As String
sql = _
    "SELECT Name, Plan " & _
    "FROM [Sheet1$] AS t1 " & _
    "INNER JOIN [Sheet2$] AS t2 ON t1.Dept = t2.Dept"

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open sql, connectionString

Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
```

You'll need to add a reference (**Tools** -> **References...**) to **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects**; choose the latest version, generally 6.1.

You can specify a given range (or a named range) within the SQL `FROM` clause as follows:

```sql
SELECT Name, Plan
FROM [Sheet1$A5:AB27] AS t1
INNER JOIN [Sheet2$] AS t2 ON t1.Dept = t2.Dept
```

The above code pastes the recordset into a third worksheet, but you can also:

- iterate over the individual rows and fields of the recordset
- extract the data in the recordset to a 2-D array, using the recordset's **GetRows* method
- generate a single long string from the recordset, using the **GetString** method

Answer (score 0):

You can join the two tables using Power Query, available in Excel 2010+.

- Use `Dept` as the key
- Change the table names in lines 2 and 5 to whatever they really are in your workbook

Examine the `Applied Steps` window to see what happens at each stage.
I think the code is pretty well self-documenting, but ask if you have any questions.

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblNameDept"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}, {"Dept", type text}}),

    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblDeptPlan"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{{"Dept", type text}, {"plan", type text}}),

    joined = Table.Join(#"Changed Type","Dept",#"Changed Type2","Dept",JoinKind.Inner),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(joined,{"Dept"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]